# Notation of 2-qubit quantum gates as "Matrix exponentiated by Matrix"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I am currently studying this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0507171) about Cartan's KAK Decomposition. In the end of the section "Canonical Class Vector" some there is a calculation on how to find the canonical class vector of a $CNOT(1\rightarrow0)$ gate. It is stated that a CNOT gate can be written as
$$\sigma_X(0)^{n(1)}$$
With $n=\frac{1}{2}(1-\sigma_Z)$. Is this notation just a different notation for a tensorproduct? Afterwards this notation is used to do some calculation and I do not understand what is happening there. Could someone provide me with a reference explaining this notation or explain to me how it works?

Edit: $\sigma_x$ changed to $\sigma_z$

Comment: I would consider this non-standard, though it feels self-explanatory (as long as it does not go wrong ... ). Note that your n should have a $\sigma_Z$. Then the n operator is just 0 or 1, depending on the whether the control qubit is zero or one, and then $\sigma_X$ to the power 0 or 1 is either the identity (control 0) or $\sigma_X$ (control 1).

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and not images for equations and math symbols.

Comment: So I removed the picture. The question is more on the notation. I do understand the calculation itself once the notaion is rewritten. To me it seems like there is a Matrix to the power of a Matrix at first. How is this even defined? I could find almost nothing on this.